# How to find maximum double in an array of integers and doubles (C++)?

Tags: c++, arrays, integer, double, max

I have an array: values[] that is populated with integers and doubles in the format of:

number of students, student id, number of grades, grade 1...grade n,...

So 2 1534 3 90.0 76.8 100.0 1245 1 99.0
would be interpreted as 2 students, student id 1534 has 3 grades (90.0, 76.8, 100.0) and student id 1245 has 1 grade (99.0).

I need to write a function that finds the largest grade in this array. My thought process is along these lines:

```
double max_grade = -1.0;

for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    if(values[i] > max_grade){
       max_grade = values[i];
    }
}
```

however I think this would compare all the values in the array and I only want to compare the doubles.

How do I only check the doubles in an array mixed with doubles and integers for the largest double?

Comment: [`std::max_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element)

Comment: An array has a single type for all the elements so if you have `double arr[]` then all the elements are `double`, not `double` and `int`

Comment: Your array won't be mixing doubles and integers. It may have doubles that hold values with no decimal component, but they are still doubles.

Comment: you are bypassing the typesystem for something that really does not need it. Structure your data in a `struct stundendInfo` with appropriate members then you can use `std::max_element` and finding the max is a one liner

Comment: You can also just start and end your for loop at a certain point in the array if you continue with your implementation

Comment: do you want to find the maximum among all grades of do you want to find the studend with the max grade ?

Comment: Could you please show us the definition of `values`?

Comment: You should first create a data structure that properly represents the properties of a "Student" in your context. It appears a student has a single ID and perhaps multiple grades. The ID would be of type int where grades may be an array of type double. Then you can make an array of this data structure to store all of your students. This is a more appropriate way to store your data. Then determining the max grade can be done in many ways, the most simple way would be something along the lines of what you've attempted.

Answer (score 3):

> I have an array: values[] that is populated with integers and doubles

Hello Zari Case,

First of all, there is no such thing as "mixed type arrays" in C or C++. If you need doubles in your array, then you need a **double** type array, which means all of your array elements will be of **double** type.

Well that isn't a problem because you can represent an integer in decimal form by specifying a **0** decimal, like this:

- 5 -> 5.0
- 1337 -> 1337.0
- 0 -> 0.0

And so on.

> So 2 1534 3 90.0 76.8 100.0 1245 1 99.0 would be interpreted as 2 students, student id 1534 has 3 grades (90.0, 76.8, 100.0) and student id 1245 has 1 grade (99.0).

If you need that exact syntax, then you can quickly code a **parser** that will go through your entries and get you the highest grade for each student.
I guess you need something like this (I appended data to your array, for the example):

```c
#include <stdio.h>

double highest_mark(double *mark_array, int number_of_marks)
{
    double max_grade = -1.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < number_of_marks; i++)
        if (mark_array[i] > max_grade)
            max_grade = mark_array[i];
    return max_grade;
}

int main()
{
    double student_info[] = {5.0, 1534.0, 3.0, 90.0, 76.8, 100.0, 1245.0, \
1.0, 99.0, 5555.0, 7.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 42.0, 2, 99.0, 98.0, \
1337.0, 1.0, 0.0};
    int number_of_students = (int)student_info[0], number_of_marks, student_id;
    int current_index = 1;

    printf("Number of students: %d\n---\n", number_of_students);
    while (number_of_students--) {
        student_id = student_info[current_index];
        number_of_marks = student_info[current_index + 1];
        printf("Student ID: %d\n", student_id);
        printf("Number of marks: %d\n", number_of_marks);
        for (int i = 0; i < number_of_marks; i++)
            printf("\tMark %d: %.1f\n", i + 1, student_info[current_index + i + 2]);
        printf("\t\tMax grade: %.1f\n", highest_mark(&student_info[current_index + 2], number_of_marks));
        current_index += (2 + number_of_marks);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

That will produce this output:

```
Number of students: 5
---
Student ID: 1534
Number of marks: 3
    Mark 1: 90.0
    Mark 2: 76.8
    Mark 3: 100.0
        Max grade: 100.0
Student ID: 1245
Number of marks: 1
    Mark 1: 99.0
        Max grade: 99.0
Student ID: 5555
Number of marks: 7
    Mark 1: 1.0
    Mark 2: 2.0
    Mark 3: 3.0
    Mark 4: 4.0
    Mark 5: 5.0
    Mark 6: 6.0
    Mark 7: 7.0
        Max grade: 7.0
Student ID: 42
Number of marks: 2
    Mark 1: 99.0
    Mark 2: 98.0
        Max grade: 99.0
Student ID: 1337
Number of marks: 1
    Mark 1: 0.0
        Max grade: 0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
double max_grade = -1.0;

for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    if(values[i] != int(values[i]) && values[i] > max_grade){
       max_grade = values[i];
    }
}
```

if values[i] is double (for example 5.2)
then 5.2 != int(5.2) because int casting will round down

but if values[i] is integer ( for example 5.0)
then 5.0 = int(5.0) because rounding down 5.0 is the same as 5.0

so if we want to make sure that values[i] is a double we need to make sure that casting values[i] to "int" will not equal the original values

That's why I added this condition before comparing with max value (values[i] != int(values[i]) )

Comment: I don't understand what's the use of casting a grade that's meant to be a double, you don't need to cast it here, also for casting you should use (int) your_value; not int() function.

Comment: int(value) is the same as (int)value, both work.
as for casting, I want to check whether the value can be int or not
for example (5.2 can never be int but 5.0 can be int )
if you cast 5.0 to int , the value remains the same
but if you cast 5.2 to int , the value will become 5.0 so the value has changed 
so, I can use casting to check whether the number can be int or not